# App is not fetching mysql db in release version in Android Pie 9

Tags: java, android, mysql

I am facing a weird issue in my app. App works smooth in all devices but not fetching data from mysql database in android pie in release version. In emulator its fine but not working on real device. I am a  teacher and the app is quiz for my students any help will be appreciated
Thanks in advance

Here is my DB helper class

I have added network_secrity xml file.

Here is my db helper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//database version
private static int db_version = 1;

//database name
private static String db_name = "quiz_level.db";

//database path string
private String db_path;


private SQLiteDatabase db;
private final Context context;

//table name
public static String TABLE_NAME = "level";

//column names

public static String CATE_ID = "cat_id";
public static String SUB_CATE_ID = "sub_cat_id";
public static String LEVEL_NO = "level_no";


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, db_name, null, db_version);
    this.context = context;

    File database = context.getDatabasePath(db_name);
    if (!database.exists()) {
        // Database does not exist so copy it from assets here
        db_path = context.getDatabasePath(db_name).toString().replace(db_name, "");

    } else {


    db_path = context.getDatabasePath(db_name).toString();

    }

}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getReadableDatabase() {
    return super.getReadableDatabase();
}

@Override
public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase() {
    return super.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}
@Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
    }
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

//delete database
public void db_delete() {
    File file = new File(db_path + db_name);
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();

    }
}

//Create a empty database on the system
public void createDatabase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        Log.v("DB Exists", "db exists");

    }

    boolean dbExist1 = checkDataBase();
    if (!dbExist1) {
        this.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            this.close();
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

//Check database already exist or not
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    boolean checkDB = false;
    try {
        String myPath = db_path + db_name;
        File dbfile = new File(myPath);
        checkDB = dbfile.exists();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    return checkDB;
}

//Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the system folder
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
    String outFileName = db_path + db_name;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(db_name);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    myInput.close();
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
}

/*
 * insert level no
 */
public void insertIntoDB(int cat_id, int sub_cat_id, int level_no) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + CATE_ID + "," + SUB_CATE_ID + "," + LEVEL_NO + ") VALUES('" + cat_id + "', '" + sub_cat_id + "', '" + level_no + "');";
    db.execSQL(query);

}

/*
 *with this method we check if categoryId & subCategoryId is already exist or not in our database
 */
public boolean isExist(int cat_id, int sub_cat_id) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE ( " + CATE_ID + " = " + cat_id + " AND " + SUB_CATE_ID + " = " + sub_cat_id + ")", null);
    boolean exist = (cur.getCount() > 0);
    cur.close();
    System.out.println("---isExit  " + (cur.getCount() > 0));
    return exist;

}

/*
 * get level
 */
public int GetLevelById(int cat_id, int sub_cat_id) {
    int level = 1;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE  (" + CATE_ID + "=" + cat_id + " AND " + SUB_CATE_ID + "=" + sub_cat_id + ")";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            level = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(LEVEL_NO));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return level;
}

/*
 * Update lavel
 */
public void UpdateLevel(int cat_id, int sub_cat_id, int level_no) {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    db.execSQL("update " + TABLE_NAME + " set level_no=" + level_no + " where (cat_id =" + cat_id + "  and  " + sub_cat_id + " = " + sub_cat_id + ")");
}}
```

Comment: you should try `db_path = context.getDatabasePath("wl.db").getPath();`

Comment: Where sir ? can you just paste in code please?

Comment: replace `db_path = context.getDatabasePath(db_name").getPath();` in the constructor

Comment: Ok thanks let me try bro

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes but still not fetching any data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201367/discussion-between-viral-videos-and-rahul-khurana).